# check all dynamically created checkbox at button click

Tags: android, checkbox

I need to check all the checkbox which is dynamically created at button click.

This is my code:

```
layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                        final View addView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
                        final Button  ItemName, Item_Qty, Amount, Total, btn_home_checkbox1, btn_home_uncheckbox1;
                      //  final Button slNo;
                        final CheckBox cb_select_Item,cb_unselect_Item;
                        final RelativeLayout checkbox_bg, uncheckbox_bg;
                        slNo = (Button) addView.findViewById(R.id.order_btn_slNo1);
                        ItemName = (Button) addView.findViewById(R.id.order_btn_ItemName1);
                        Item_Qty = (Button) addView.findViewById(R.id.order_btn_Qty1);
                        Amount = (Button) addView.findViewById(R.id.order_btn_amount1);
                        Total = (Button) addView.findViewById(R.id.order_btn_total1);
                        checkbox_bg = (RelativeLayout) addView.findViewById(R.id.order_rl_checkBox1);
                        uncheckbox_bg = (RelativeLayout) addView.findViewById(R.id.order_rl_uncheckBox1);
                        cb_select_Item = (CheckBox) addView.findViewById(R.id.home_checkbox1);
                        cb_unselect_Item = (CheckBox) addView.findViewById(R.id.home_uncheckbox1);

 container.addView(addView);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try to get all check box count from parent layout and iterate each check box and change checked value to true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
checkbox.setChecked(true);
```

to check a checkbox programmatically. You can add multiple lines in button OnClick method.

Comment: Thanks for you answer.But how can I use your answer for 10 checkbox which I created dynamically using inflater.

Comment: private LinearLayout container;LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                        final View addView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null); final CheckBox cb_select_Item;cb_select_Item = (CheckBox) addView.findViewById(R.id.home_checkbox1); container.addView(addView);